# CSS selector not working — Truncated by Selenium WebDriver

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

I have this property:

```
public IEnumerable<Drawing> Drawings { 
    get { 
        return Root.FindComponents<Drawing>(By.CssSelector("tbody tr[role='row']")); 
    } 
}
```

Which calls this extension method:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> FindComponents<T>(this IWebElement element, By by) where T : PageComponent, new() {
    return element.FindElements(by).Select((el) => {
        T t = new T();
        t.Root = el;
        return t;
    });
}
```

When I look in the watch window in Visual Studio, my selector has been truncated to the part after `tbody` and now just says `tr[role='row']` and it's highlighted in red in the watch window.

This ends up selecting some of the wrong elements.

What is going on? Why am I not able to use this perfectly valid selector? The selector works in the targeted browser (FireFox) when I use `document.querySelectorAll`.

Here is the html structure:

(the table is the Root element)

```
<table role="grid">
    <colgroup>
        <col style="width:35px" />
        <col style="width:35px" />
        <col style="width:35px" />
        <col style="width:35px" />
        <col style="width:120px" />
        <col style="width:35px" />
        <col style="width:35px" />
        <col style="width:40px" />
    </colgroup>
    <tbody role="rowgroup">
        <tr role="row">
            <td role="gridcell"></td>
            <td role="gridcell"></td>
            <td role="gridcell"></td>
            <td role="gridcell"></td>
            <td role="gridcell"></td>
            <td role="gridcell"></td>
            <td role="gridcell"></td>
            <td role="gridcell"></td>
        </tr>
        <!-- ... etc (repeats like the above) -->
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: I can't really follow this question: there are references to "watch" plus some code I can't quite follow, but no evidence of an error, and no HTML or way of recreating. As you say, the CSS query is fine, but I can't believe that Selenium itself is truncating it. Are you quite sure this isn't working?

Comment: @AndrewRegan Absolutely. Selenium is removing it or some other issue is truncating the selector. And it is highlighted in the watch window in Visual Studio during debug in a red color.

Comment: Can you post some HTML for us to look at? Seems the answer is not as straightforward as one may think (looking at the 'answers').

Comment: Eventually, I have no time right now. If it helps though, it's a kendo data grid.

Comment: Hmmm, I've never had my selector cropped. Weird stuff man. Something you probably tried already, but does `tbody[role='rowgroup'] tr[role='row']` work (just guessing it may not be cropped then).

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is at all helpful...

Found this resource https://saucelabs.com/resources/selenium/css-selectors

Which would suggest replacing your selector like so:

```
tbody tr[@role='row']
```

or

```
tbody>tr[@role='row']
```

Not sure if either will work any better but worth a try I guess.

*Note: I notice it has already been recommended to use `>` but not in conjunction with `@role` as far as I can see.*

Comment: Is the @ sign important?

Comment: @KthProg seems to be what the article suggests... worth a try?

Comment: I'll give it a try and let you know :)

Comment: @KthProg interestingly enough, using the @ symbol with document.querySelectorAll doesn't work.

Comment: Same problem: `Sequence contains no elements.`. I didn't check to see if it truncates the selector again or not.

Comment: @KthProg is document.querySelectorAll definitely returning the correct results?

Answer (score 0):

You're essentially using a child selector in your code but the problem I believe is that your not defining the root element first, it would also make more sense to us a descendant selector which will account for multiple 'tr' selections in the future should you decide to reuse that tag.

A child selector would look like the following:

```
return Root.FindComponents<Drawing>(By.CssSelector("Table>tbody>tr[role='row']"));
```

Where '>' is being used to denote a linear path to the element that you require.

A descendant selector should look something like:

```
return Root.FindComponents<Drawing>(By.CssSelector("Table tbody tr[role='row']"));
```

The only difference between the above and yours is that it defines the root element of the html style sheet. The descendant selector also allows a greater scope for your selection query. I'd suggest trying it and seeing if it works as intended, it is entirely possible that I have misinterpreted the documentation. If that is the case let me know and we can look into the issue in more detail. Apologies if you have already tried the above, I figure it's worth adopting a process of elimination here.

Comment: I haven't had time to test this yet, but I'll re-open the bounty after it expires and award it if this works.

Answer (score 0):

I can't verify this because I'm not working on that project anymore, but I believe my version of chrome driver was not correct for the version of Chrome I was testing on. If someone else come across an issue like this, I would recommend checking those versions to make sure they match.

Answer (score -1):

The CSS path should be `"tbody>tr[role='row']"`

For more CSS related concerns you can watch out [this video](https://goo.gl/i4hyfb). It'll help you to design your css path in multiple ways.

Comment: Using that selector does not fix the problem. I tried that first, trust me.